# What is the difference between 乾 and 幹?

Tags: difference, characters

I know that dry is "乾燥", but according to Google Translate:

- dried apples = 蘋果乾
- dried apricots = 杏乾
- dried mangosteens = 山竹果乾
- dried durians = 榴蓮幹
- dried yeast = 幹酵母
- dried chickpeas = 幹鷹嘴豆
- dried cranberries = 蔓越莓幹

What is the difference between 乾 and 幹?

Comment: In this specific context, the 幹 should all be 乾. They made a mistake converting simplified to traditional I suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a noun, only '乾' means 'dried product' While 幹 as a noun means 'tree trunk'.  They are two different words

'乾' as an adjective means 'dry'

Both 乾 and 幹 were simplified to 干 in simplified Chinese

Sometimes when people translate simplified Chinese back to traditional Chinese 干 was wrongly translated as 幹 instead of 乾, or vice versa. For example 蘋果乾 --> 苹果干 -->蘋果幹(wrongly translate 干 as 幹 instead of 乾); 幹好工作 -->干好工作 --> 乾好工作 (wrongly translate 干 as 乾 instead of 幹)

Similarly

Both 發 and 髮 are simplified to 发

I had seen many instances of  紅髮 --> 红发 --> 紅發 (wrongly translate 发 as 發 instead of 髮)

Even Google Translate makes the [same mistake](https://translate.google.ca/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=zh-TW&text=red%20hair) 
[image]

Answer (score 4):

「乾」 (Baxter-Sagart OC: **/*[k]ˤar/**) is the original character meaning *dry*. Using 「幹」 for *dry* was sometimes found in history, but in Modern Chinese this should be considered a spelling mistake.

「幹」 is a corruption of 「榦」. 「榦」 is comprised of semantic 「木」 and phonetic 「倝」, indicating the meaning *tree trunk*, extended to mean *main body* > *main organisation, cadre, framework* > *to conduct, to do*. 「木」 was sometimes corrupted into 「干」 to give an additional sound hint, producing 「幹」, and this is the variant that the Taiwan and Hong Kong standards use.

---

[「干」 depicts a *two-pronged weapon*](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=59), but this meaning is no longer used. Most other meanings you find with this character are phonetic loans; it is now most commonly used for the [*Heavenly Stems*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavenly_Stems) (天干地支), unless you're learning Simplified Chinese.

「乾」 is sometimes pronounced **qián** (OC: **/*[ɡ](r)ar/**), meaning *sky, heaven*. This is a phonetic loan.